# How to get beautiful soup function to get URLs from next page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have this craigslist aggregator application and I want to get the url link of each listing on the page.

Right now i can get listing title, price, date posted, and distance from zip code from each page in the `load_craigslist_url()`. The `extract_post_urls()` returns me a list of urls, but i noticed I was only getting one page's listings URLs not the subsequent pages listings urls.

I put extract_post_urls() function in the function that controls going to next page. I made a list links[] and had `links.append(self.extract_post_urls())` that gave me the list of URLs, but when I went to the next page, the list was appended but with the urls from the first page not the current page that is being scraped.

I tried `.append` and `.extend` and both gave me just lists of urls from the first page not the current page being scraped

Controls going to next page

```
def load_craigslist_url(self):

    links = []
    data = []  # List that will hold all of the information scraped
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    while True:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,
                                                       "searchform")))  # Once the driver find the web elemet 'searchform' it knows the full page is loaded
            print("Page is loaded")

            data.append(self.extract_post_information())  # Append the data found from the extract post method into the data list
            links.append(self.extract_post_urls())
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                            '//*[@id="searchform"]/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]'))).click()  # Wait after clicking 'next page' if there is a next page else break
        except:
            print("Last page")
            break

    return data, links
```

Scrapes listings data from current page

Gets url links of each listing on the current page

```
def extract_post_urls(self):
    url_list = []
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "result-title hdrlnk"}):
        # print(link)
        url_list.append(link["href"])
    return url_list
```

My list looks like

```
links
                   0: [https://newyork.....]
                   1: [https://newyork.....]
```

just that for as many pages a certain item has on craigslist. the index is equal to the page that was scraped. So page 1 listings URLs are in index 0 and page 2 is in index 1 and so on

Comment: You need share your link to diagonos?

Comment: https://southjersey.craigslist.org/search/bia?search_distance=44&postal=08205&max_price=500  That is the link I am using. Every time you go to next page, there is a 's=' variable that appears keeping track og how many items you viewed. Example this is the link after going to page 3. I would of viewed 360 listings https://southjersey.craigslist.org/search/bia?s=360&max_price=500&postal=08205&search_distance=44

Comment: That first page link is self.url =  f"https://{location}.craigslist.org/search/sss?&max_price={max_price}&postal={postal_code}&query={query}&20card&search_distance={radius}". after I go to next page that link like I said earlier adds the 's='  before 'max_price='. Could the reason why my method is only getting the first pages html links is due to self.url not updating when i go to next page? So it continously scrapes only what self.url is in the beggining?

Comment: sorry, 's=' is between postal and search distance

Comment: Added the answer.Let me know how it goes!!!